# Identifying subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: finite-groups, gap

I am trying to use GAP to identify subgroups of $S_n$ with two generators. As an example, in one case the generators are $a=(1~2)(3~4)$ and $b=(1~3)$, in which case $\langle a,b \rangle \cong D_4$. However, many of the groups I'd like to identify are much larger.

A group that I have not yet identified has generators $a=(1~2~3)(4~5~6)(7~8~9)(10~11~12)$ and $b=(1~7)(2~10)(4~8)(5~11)$. Using the IdGroup function in GAP, I have determined that it is the $72$nd group of order $96$ in the SmallGroup library. If I ask GAP for the $72$nd group of order $96$ in the SmallGroup library, it says it is a polycyclic group with $6$ generators, but that does not tell me the structure of the group.

Are there some other techniques I can use in GAP to understand the group $\langle a,b\rangle$ in terms of familiar groups (that are smaller than $S_{12}$)? I would like a technique that is as general as possible, since I will be trying to identify many more groups with different generators.

Comment: You can use [SmallGroupsInformation(96);](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_96) in gap to obtain more information; e.g., Frattini factors etc. What exactly do you mean by "the structure of the group"?

Comment: Presumably there's more than one polycyclic group with $6$ generators and order $96$, so "polycyclic group with $6$ generators" does not determine the group. My hope is to recognize the group as something like $D_{6}$ or $A_4 \ltimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ or something like that (obviously those do not even have the correct order). That may be too much to hope for, though.

Comment: You can recognise the group as one of the $231$ groups of order $96$, by obtaining the explicit group table. However, not all have a "nice" name. So you expect too much, I fear.

Comment: You might want to look at section 3.20 of http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/howtogap.pdf for some of the available functions. In general the question is whether you care about an abstract group structure or a permutational structure. Very few groups are meaningful products, but generic extensions.

Comment: The group given by your $a$ and $b$ is transitive, `TransitiveIdentification` returns index number 60 in the list of transitive groups of degree 12, but the transitive group name `[1/2[1/2.2^2]^3]2A_4(6)_4` might not really be helpful here. There also is `StructureDescription` but it is limited in scope and the names produced are often misleading.